# Display a Wordpress website on a subdirectory of a Drupal website

Tags: web-hosting, dns, cdn, reverse-proxy

**My company's website is on Drupal**. Let's say the website domain is blue.com

We just acquired another company "Acme" and their website is on **Wordpress**, and it HAS to stay on Wordpress.

-We need "blue.com/acme" to show Acme's Wordpress website (which will be on a separate hosting environment) (Company leadership does NOT want to use a subdomain, it has to be a subdirectory URL structure.)

-while "blue.com" continues to pull up the Drupal site.

I've looked into split-hosting and reverse proxies but not sure...

Comment: If it's going to be on separate hosting it really should be a sub domain. Reverse proxies between completely separate hosting is dirt slow which will hurt usability and SEO.

Comment: I agree with Stephen, you don't want that headache.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention they are on separate servers / hosting environment, follow the next steps:

1. Create a new **subdomain** acme.blue.com
2. Edit your **Apache configuration** on the main domain's server (blue.com).

Add the following code:

```
ProxyPass "/acme"  "https://acme.blue.com/"
ProxyPassReverse "/acme"  "https://acme.blue.com/"
```

You can find a little more information on the [Apache manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) if you want to dig deeper on what else you can do, for example, add load-balancing.

Answer (score 2):

I would put both sites on one server and install WordPress in a subdirectory inside of `/var/www/html/`. I do this sort of thing for international/multilingual sites all of the time.

Drupal gets installed here

`/var/www/html/`

WordPress gets installed here

`/var/www/html/blue/`

### Example Nginx Config

Feel free to adjust as needed, or if I made a mistake. I didn't see any server-specific requirements included in your question. Apache would look different, I don't use it.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blue.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; # Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name blue.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/blue.com.crt; # Path to SSL certificate, adjusted to match server_name
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/blue.com.key; # Path to SSL certificate key, adjusted to match server_name
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Recommended TLS protocols
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5; # Recommended cipher suite
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # Root for Drupal Installation
    root /var/www/html/;

    # Main Drupal site configuration
    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    # WordPress Installation in /acme/
    location ^~ /acme/ {
        alias /var/www/html/acme/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /acme/index.php?$args;

        location ~ ^/acme/(.*\.php)$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

This will result in the subdirectory URL structure that your company's leadership desires, and be easy for you to manage.